# How can you add an external object to a DataSource using wave analytics in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to use external objects as part of a DataSource in SalesForce Wave Analytics, but after starting Data Synchronization I receive an error that states that object is not supported:

> Error executing node 101: Object SalesOrderLineItemSet__x is not
>   supported (0Bw360000005RhtCAE_0Bq360000000WWsCAM)

After reading SalesForce documentation seems that External Objects are not allowed, and the only way to import data into Wave analytics is by importing a CSV file or using External Data API, but it's not clearly stated that is prohibited and want to share this question to get feedback from the experts.

Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

after doing some research I finally found that it is not allowed to use external objects in SalesForce Wave (as of winter'16 edition).

I tried different approaches and I finally found that it is possible to import CSV files as Datasets, and after importing the data you can transform it using Dataflows.

What was really difficult to find out reading the documentation is how to access those datasets from the DataFlow, so I'll explain it heere in case someone reach this situation:
Sintax is:

```
name_of_the_activity : {
   "action": "edgemart",
   "parameters": { "alias": name_of_the_ataSource }
}
```

In the following example I'm creating an object inside the DataFlow with name: "**Extract_VH_Currency**", that will perform an edgemart action over the "**VH_Currency**" Dataset that I have already imported into Wave from any external resource.

```
"Extract_VH_Currency": {
        "action": "edgemart",
        "parameters": { "alias": "VH_Currency" }
 },
```

After doing so, you can now reference the external datasource as "**Extract_VH_Currency**" in any other activity performed by the dataflow, such as augments, or any other transformation that you should need to integrate external information in your Wave BI.

Hope it helps!